# Testing Spring Actuator Info Values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-boot-actuator

I am writing some mockMvc unit tests for my actuator. I currently have one for health, which works fine

```
class HealthTest {
  @Autowired
  private Mockmvc mockMvc;

  private ResultActions resultActions;

  @BeforeEach() throws Exception {
    resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/actuator/health"));
  }

  @Test
  void shouldReturnOk() throws Exception {
    resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath("status", is("UP")));
  }
}
```

This works fine. However, when apply the same logic to "/actuator/info" (literally the exact same as the health class, with only that path changed (with config defined in the application.yml, and I have reviewed this manually, it's there when I run the application) I get a 200 status back, but no JSON, even though the web page itself shows a JSON object. It's like when I run it through this, it gets a blank page back, or the page, but not in json format.

Edit: So the config is in the main/application.yml. When I replicate the config to the test/application.yml, it works. Is there a way to get mvc to point to my main application.yml? As all this really tests is my duplicated test config

Edit 2: Better formatting of comment:

```
management:
   endpoints:
    web:
     exposure:
     include:
     - info 

info:
 application:
   name: My application name
```

Answer (score 1):

`/actuator/info` provides your customized information. The default is empty information. Therefore, you must create a Spring bean to provide this information, for example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.info.Info;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.info.InfoContributor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BuildInfoContributor implements InfoContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("version", "2.0.0.M7");
        builder.withDetails(data);
    }
}
```

And test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class Test {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private ResultActions resultActions;

    @BeforeEach()
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        resultActions = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/actuator/info"));
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturnOk() throws Exception {
        resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath("version", is("2.0.0.M7")));
    }
}
```

Comment: My actuator info at present does work, just with the main application.yml having

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
        - info

info:
  application:
    name: My application name
```

Comment: Yes, if you have `application.yml` in your test/resources, you should override all the properties you need, including `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include`. Otherwise define with profile - `application-test.yml`, then all properties from both files will be merged.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. So it turns out the test resources file can't be called `application.yml`, it needs it's own profile, or it totally overrides the main one.

Comment: and what exactly did you write in the new application-actuator.yml file? Copy from the application.yml from resources? :-/ I also get this error that it can not connect to the database :-/